# Calcular quantidade pelo número inteiro

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho que inserir um registro no banco de dados de acordo com um número inteiro. Por exemplo, 20, 21, 22, 23...29 Eu pego o primeiro número (no caso 2) e insiro 2 registros. Se for 10, 11, 12, 13...19 (no caso 1) eu insiro 1 registro. 0,1,2,3,4...9 eu insiro nenhum...

Só preciso saber se é de 0 a 9, 10 a 11, 20 a 22 e assim por diante. De acordo qual número for eu pego o primeiro número. O problema de fazer por exemplo com `substr` é se o número for 100 então ele "pensará" que é valores entre 10 e 19.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divida por 10, pegue a parte inteira, e utilize o resultado nas suas verificações. Por exemplo:

```
$dezenas = floor($num / 10);
if ($dezenas == 1) {

} else if ($dezenas == 2) {

} // etc.
```